# Count items based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The initial state of the store is:

```
let initialState = {
  items: [],
  itemsCount: 0,
  completedCount: 0
};
```

When I dispatch an action with the type `ADD_ITEM` the new item is added to the `items` array and `itemsCount` is incremented (Although I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly)

```
case "ADD_ITEM": {
  return {
    ...state,
    items: [
      ...state.items,
      {
        title: action.name,
        dateCreated: action.date,
        id: action.id,
        isChecked: false
      }
    ],
    itemsCount: state.items.length + 1
  };
}
```

and for `TOGGLE_ITEM`

```
case "TOGGLE_ITEM": {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    items: state.items.map(item => {
      if (item.id !== action.id) {
        return item;
      }
      return Object.assign({}, item, {
        isChecked: !item.isChecked
      });
    })
  });
}
```

When I dispatch an action with the type `REMOVE_ITEM` the following is executed:

```
case "REMOVE_ITEM": {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    items: [...state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)],
    itemsCount: state.items.length - 1
  });
}
```

Now I'm trying to count the items that have `isChecked` is `true`

```
state.items.map(item => {
    if(item.isChecked){
        //Increment count
    }
})
```

I'm not sure where exactly to do that.

Inside the `TOGGLE_ITEM` action?

Inside a new `COUNT_ITEM` action? if so, when is that action dispatched?

And how do assign an incremented digit to part of the state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just compute it when you need it in your actions/components etc:

```
items.filter(item => item.isChecked).length
```

It's not a good practice to store derived values such as the count of certain items (including the `itemsCount` variable) in your state (reasons similar to why you normalise your state).

If you are worried about performance (it's O(n) so shouldn't be much of an issue in general), you can use a [memoization library](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).

Answer (score 2):

The count needs to be recalculated on `TOGGLE_ITEM` as well as `ADD/REMOVE_ITEM`. And the count reducer could use reduce like

```
state.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if(item.isChecked){
        acc += 1;
    }
    return acc;
}, 0)
```

However, you are better of not storing the COUNT in the reducer since it is directly derivable from items, you can simply calculate the count using a `memoized selector` in your `mapStateToProps` function. You could make use of [`reselect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) for writing memoized selectors or create your own

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note, in order to reduce the extra overhead in your action code:

```
case "ADD_ITEM": {
  let items=state.items
  items.push({
      title: action.name,
      dateCreated: action.date,
      id: action.id,
      isChecked: false
    })
  return {
    ...state,
    items: items,
    itemsCount: state.itemsCount+1
  };
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. It turns items array in the state into a number and fails `map` or `filter`

Comment: You are right `push()` returns an integer, I've updated the post.

Comment: I'm trying to learn as many CS terminologies as I can. What do you mean by "extra overhead" ? Is there a point where I'll get stuck in a problem because of the previous structure or is it true that everything has a workaround with coding?