# how many items inside list contains a word

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
let list: Array<string> = ['abc', 'efg', 'abcde', 'eefg'];
```

I wonder how can I check how many items inside list contains `abc` (a count).

I know that I can use `indexOf` inside loop but I wonder if there any other, easier, convenient way.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50227082/1233251

Comment: Anything else will be the same approach. Loop and count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to filter the list and get the length:

```
let count = list.filter(s => s.includes(word)).length;
```

Using `indexOf`:

```
let count = list.filter(s => s.indexOf(word) > -1).length;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here'a solution with `reduce()`

```js
const list = ['abc', 'efg', 'abcde', 'eefg']

const countReduce = list.reduce((count, item) => {
  return count += item.includes('abc') ? 1 : 0
}, 0)

console.log('reduce:', countReduce)
```

And here's one with regexp:

```js
const list = ['abc', 'efg', 'abcde', 'eefg']

const count = (list.join(',').match(/abc/g) || []).length;

console.log(count);
```

And still a string concatenation style:

```js
const list = ['abc', 'efg', 'abcde', 'eefg']

const count = list.join(',').split('abc').length - 1

console.log(count);
```

A bit more complicated one - treating the string as an array (and NOT using indexOf... :) )

```js
const list = ['abc', 'efg', 'abcdeabc', 'eefg']

let count = 0

for (let item of list) {
  let onlyOnce = 0 // guarding that the string is counted inly once/item
  const length = item.length
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (item[i] + item[i + 1] + item[i + 2] == 'abc' && !onlyOnce) {
      count++
      onlyOnce++
    }
  }
}

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function isEqualTo(value) {
  return value.includes("abc"); // or return value == "abc";  // whatever you want
}
var words = list.filter(isEqualTo).length
```

Comment: The OP wants a `contains` filter rather than `equals`.